# Multi-Array read not Variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var langeJSON = {
 "placeholder":
 [
  { "#colEmail01"   : "Hello you" }
 ]
}

var result = langeJSON["placeholder"]["#colEmail01"]; // is empty ???
```

Why result is empty?

Comment: Do you know what an array is (the things inside `[]`) and how to access their elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
langeJSON["placeholder"][0]["#colEmail01"]
```

You define `placeholder` as array, not just one object.

And if you want to use `langeJSON["placeholder"]["#colEmail01"];`, you should build your json as:

```
var langeJSON = {
  "placeholder": { "#colEmail01": "Hello you" }
}
var result = langeJSON["placeholder"]["#colEmail01"];
```

Comment: Downvoter, please describe, what wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the langeJSON doesn't have an index called "text". instead it has a key called "placeholder". You can fetch the result by doing the following (assuming this is in javascript, looking at the code):

```
var langeJSON = {
    "placeholder":
    [
        { "#colEmail01"         : "Hello you" }
    ]
}

var result = langeJSON["placeholder"][0]["#colEmail01"]; // should return "Hello you"
```

Comment: my bad, forgot to add the index ;-) should work now

Answer (score 0):

You don't use this as an array, first you have to parse this to get the result.

```
var langeJSON = '{ "placeholder": [ { "colEmail01": "Hello you" } ] }'; var ll  =   JSON.parse(langeJSON); var result = ll.placeholder[0].colEmail01;
```

Comment: Need also to `JSON.stringify` js object before parse? :)